# How to fix an Event Loop Closed Error on discord.py

Tags: discord.py

When I run my bot, I get an error message that says "Runtime Error: Event loop is closed"

```
class Client(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="/", intents = discord.Intents.all())

        self.cogslist = ["cogs.cog1"]

    async def setup_hook(self):
        for ext in self.cogslist:
            await self.load_extension(ext)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Am ready!")
        channel = client.get_channel(BOTCHANNEL_ID)
        await channel.send("UP.")
        try:
            synced = await client.tree.sync()
            print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

I've figured out that the issue only happens when I try to define my bot as the above, and not when it is simple (as in the example below)

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents = discord.Intents.all(), case_insensitive=True)
```

Running the first example leads to the error, while running the second leads to the bot running; however, I am trying to get the bot to work from the first block and haven't been able to figure out what I need to fix.

Note: I am a novice at this and it is likely I have made a simple error, also open to suggestions.

Comment: We need more code on the working version. See [mre]

Comment: In addition to that, it‘s generally a bad idea to call a subclassed Bot or instance of it „client“. A client in discord.py is the base class that connects to Discords API and sends/receives events/messages. A Bot is a subclass of Client which implements interfaces and helpers to create commands. To create good readable code, you should rename it to `bot` and the subclass to `Bot`